# Separating Redirects from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, 301-redirect

I'm migrating my server to a different location. I have a bunch of changed URL's (50 or so) that I need to 301 redirect to new locations. I use Apache 2.4

Is there a way to separate them from .htaccess to different file(s) just for the sake of organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only use one distributed config file per directory. You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file use a `<Directory>` block instead.